# Как поменять цвет текста в ячейке C1TrueDBGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Я знаю как это делается на обычном **DataGridView**, например: `DataGridView.Rows[2].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;`

Как сделать тоже самое на **C1TrueDBGrid** (или **True DB Grid**) из библиотеки **ComponentOne**? (без использование событий).

Ну или хотя-бы как поменять цвет всей строки?

Comment: думаю это нужно спрашивать в саппорте кастомной библиотеки, смотреть в документации к библиотеке или же спрашивать на форуме посвященном библиотеке. Маловероятно что этой библиотекой здесь кто-то пользуется.

Comment: `DataGrid` - это контрол из WPF, изменил заголвок, чтобы не вносить путаницу.

Comment: Если вам нужно настроить `C1TrueDBGrid`, то и спрашивайте именно про него. Почему у вас в заголовке спрашивается совсем про другое? Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Судя по документации: [C1TrueDBGrid.Style.ForeColor](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/docs/c1truedbgrid/c1winc1truedbgridstyleforecolorproperty.htm) - всё то же самое. Не?

Comment: Вы вообще в документацию заглядывали? [Applying Cell Styles by Status](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/docs/c1truedbgrid/applyingcellstylesbystatus.htm)

Comment: Вот вам ещё [статейка](https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/change-background-for-modified-cells-in-c1truedbgrid)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем кто откликнулся. Решил проблему, и пришлось использовать событие.

Использовал событие **FetchCellStyle**.

Определение **FetchCellStyle** - Occurs whenever a cell is to be rendered and the C1DisplayColumn.FetchStyle is true.

Вот код:

```
private void DetailTGrid_FetchCellStyle(object sender, FetchCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
    decimal sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= DetailTGrid.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        sum = Convert.ToDecimal(DetailTGrid[i, 4]) * Convert.ToDecimal(DetailTGrid[i, 6]);

        if (sum != Convert.ToDecimal(DetailTGrid[i, 9]))
        {
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }        
}
```

По умолчанию FetchCellStyle будет отключён и не будет вызываться. Чтобы FetchCellStyle работала, нужно присвоить значение **True** для свойства **FetchStyle** для нужной колонки.

Для этого нужно: Открыть список свойств C1TrueDBGrid -> Открыть коллекцию свойства **Columns** -> Выбрать нужный столбик который FetchCellStyle будет отрабатывать -> и в списке свойств этого столбца найти свойство FetchStyle и присвоить **True**.